# calculate age from date of birth and program start date

Tags: oracle

I have two tables: `ch` and `pe`

I need to calculate age of the clients from the Person (pe) table. I tried this function:

```
(ch.STARTDATE - pe.DATEOFBIRTH) / 365 AS AGE
```

This works but is not fully accurate, can someone please help me calculate age of a person in Oracle using the program start date and their birth date? Thank you

Comment: What do you call "accurate"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the built in function [`MONTHS_BETWEEN`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/MONTHS_BETWEEN.html#GUID-E4A1AEC0-F5A0-4703-9CC8-4087EB889952). As the age is typically counted in *years*, simple divide by 12 and truncate to the whole number:

```
trunc(MONTHS_BETWEEN(ch.STARTDATE,pe.DATEOFBIRTH)/12) age
```

Examples - birthday today

```
select trunc(MONTHS_BETWEEN(DATE'2021-03-04',DATE'2000-03-04')/12) age  from dual;
       AGE
----------
        21
```

Birthday tomorrow

```
select trunc(MONTHS_BETWEEN(DATE'2021-03-04',DATE'2000-03-05')/12) age  from dual;        
       AGE
----------
        20
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this do?

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE function f_age (par_birth_date in date,
  2                                    par_date_to    in date default trunc(sysdate))
  3     return varchar2
  4  is
  5    /* Based on someone's birth date, function returns their age
  6    */
  7    retval   varchar2 (30);
  8  begin
  9     retval :=
 10           trunc (months_between (par_date_to, par_birth_date) / 12)
 11           || ' years ' ||                                                               -- years
 12           lpad (trunc (mod (months_between (par_date_to, par_birth_date), 12)), 2, ' ')
 13           || ' months '  ||                                                             -- months
 14           lpad (
 15              trunc (
 16                 par_date_to
 17                 - add_months (
 18                      par_birth_date,
 19                      trunc (months_between (par_date_to, par_birth_date) / 12) * 12
 20                      + trunc (mod (months_between (par_date_to, par_birth_date), 12)))),
 21              2,
 22              ' ')
 23           || ' days ';                                                                  -- days
 24
 25     return (trim(retval));
 26  end f_age;
 27  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_age(date '2000-09-14', date '2021-03-04') age from dual;

AGE
------------------------------
20 years  5 months 18 days

SQL>
```

---

In your case, you'd call it as

```
select f_age(pe.dateofbirth, ch.startdate) 
from pe join ch on ...
```